# How to find the Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac{2}{(z-4)}-\frac{3}{(z+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

How to find the Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac{2}{(z-4)}-\frac{3}{(z+1)}$ for $1 < |z| <4$, $|z| > 4$, $|z| < 4$, $|z| > 1$ and $|z| < 5$?

For $1 < |z| <4$ and $|z| > 4$ I found the answer in [[Find the Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac{2}{(z-4)}-\frac{3}{(z+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673850/find-the-laurent-series-for-fz-frac2z-4-frac3z1?rq=1) ] to be

For $|z| < 4$,

$$\begin{align}\frac 2{z - 4} &= \frac 2{-4}\frac 1{1 - \frac z 4}\\
&=\frac {-1}2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac z4\right)^n\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {z^n}{2^{2n+1}}\end{align}$$

For $|z| > 4$,
$$\begin{align}\frac 2{z - 4} &= \frac 2{z}\frac 1{1 - \frac 4 z}\\
&=\frac 2z\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac 4z\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {2^{2n+1}}{z^{n+1}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {2^{2n-1}}{z^{n}}\end{align}$$

for $|z| < 1$,$$\begin{align}\frac {-3}{z + 1} &= -3\frac 1{1 - (-z)}\\
&=-3\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-z)^n\\
&=-3\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nz^n\end{align}$$
for $|z| > 1$ $$\begin{align}\frac {-3}{z + 1} &= \frac {-3}z\frac 1{1 - (-\frac 1z)}\\
&=\frac {-3}z\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac 1z\right)^n\\
&=3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{z^{n+1}}\\
&=3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{n}}{z^{n}}\end{align}$$

Hence for $|z| < 1$,
$$f(z) = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {z^n}{2^{2n+1}} - 3\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nz^n = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1 + 3(-1)^n}{2^{2n+1}}z^n$$
For $1 < |z| < 4$,
$$f(z) = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {z^n}{2^{2n+1}} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {3(-1)^{n}}{z^{n}}$$
For $4 < |z|$,
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {2^{2n-1}}{z^{n}} + 3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{n}}{z^{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n-1} + 3(-1)^n}{z^n}$$

How to find the Laurent series for $|z| > 1$, $|z| < 4$ and $|z| < 5$?