# How to find Laurent series where there is a singularity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series

If we consider

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}=\frac{1}{(z-2)}-\frac{1}{(z-1)}$$

I know how to calculate the Laurent series for $|z|<1, |z|>2$ and $1<|z|<2$. But I am not sure how to calculate the Laurent series for $|z|>1$ and $|z|>0$ where there is a singularity.

How to calculate the Laurent series for $f(z)$ for $|z|>0$ since the function becomes singular at $z=1$ and $z=2$?

Comment: Isn't it just a Taylor series, that blows up at $z=1$?

Comment: @Michael, could you elaborate more please?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1/2}{1-z/2}$.  There is a singularity at $z=1$, so you can't get it to work further than that.

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212793/how-to-find-the-laurent-series-for-fz-frac2z-4-frac3z1?rq=1 to know how to work in different zones.